# Digital Ocean LAMP stack z-panel installation “cannot execute binary file” on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 32-bit, lamp

Having an issue installing z-panel on a Digital Ocean VPS running Ubuntu 12.04. Specifically, when I try to execute the installer I get the following error:

```
installer-10-1-0-ubuntu-64.sh.x: cannot execute binary file.
```

Can anyone shed any light on this error? I've re-attempted the install about five times with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out …

The one-click LAMP install on Ubuntu 12.04 from Digital Ocean is 32-bit, not 64-bit. Downloaded and installed the Z-Panel 32-bit package no problem.